# tkinter and virtual event

Tags: python, tkinter

Do you know why this code is not working ?

```
from tkinter import *


def myhandler(evt):
    lbl=Label(root, text="I am in myHandler")
    lbl.place(x=60, y=50)

root = Tk()

root.bind("<<myevent>>", myhandler)
root.event_generate("<<myevent>>", when="now" )

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: It may be that the `mainloop()` is not running when `event_generate()` is executed.  It works when using `after()` to schedule `event_generate()`, i.e. `root.after(1000, lambda: root.event_generate('<<myevent>>', when='now'))`.

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: It's exactly that. thank you very much